# How to make a skybox texture visible on orthographic camera?

Tags: camera, world, orthographic, shader-nodes

I'm working on a 2d render and have the camera perspective set to orthographic.
I'm using the world shader nodes but every time I look through my camera the texture is just a plain color!
I need it to look orthographic, but is there any way I can fix this?

here's a screenshot of what the problem is (*this is a placeholder background btw*) [image: good]

[image: bad]

Comment: In orthographic view, all camera rays are parallel, and environment spheres are an infinite distance away. Therefore, in orthographic mode, all rays hit the same pixel on the image.

Comment: oh, I think I understand. thank you for the answer!